# Golang elasticsearch TypedClient Aggregation how to loop over results

Tags: go, elasticsearch

I am using the official Elasticsearch Go Typed Client package from Elastic to query for uniq service names, for this I built an aggregate search. The query succeeds and the response contains the Buckets with the service names. Now I want to loop over the Buckets and read the service names.

Using the untyped client this is as easy as looping over response.Aggregations.StermsServices.Buckets. But with the Typed client I cannot figure out how to do this (lack of knowledge on how to use the correct types and syntax I guess).

```
func GetServices(env string) (Services, error) {
    var result Services
    var err error

    es, err := elasticsearch.NewTypedClient(cfg)
    if err != nil {
        return Services{}, fmt.Errorf("error creating the client: %s", err)
    }

    res, err := es.Search().
        Index(env).
        Aggregations(map[string]types.Aggregations{
            "services": {
                Terms: &types.TermsAggregation{
                    Field: some.String("serviceName.keyword"),
                },
            },
        }).
        Size(0).
        Do(context.Background())

    if err != nil {
        return Services{}, fmt.Errorf("error runnning search query: %s", err)
    }

    items := &types.TermsAggregateBaseStringTermsBucket{}
    items.Buckets = res.Aggregations["services"]

    for _, bucket := range items.Buckets {
      // Do something with bucket.Key
    }

    return result, err
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten it to work using a lot of type assertion, which doesn't feel ideal:

```
func GetServices(env string) (Services, error) {
    var result Services
    var err error

    es, err := elasticsearch.NewTypedClient(cfg)
    if err != nil {
        return Services{}, fmt.Errorf("error creating the client: %s", err)
    }

    res, err := es.Search().
        Index(env).
        Aggregations(map[string]types.Aggregations{
            "services": {
                Terms: &types.TermsAggregation{
                    Field: some.String("serviceName.keyword"),
                },
            },
        }).
        Size(0).
        Do(context.Background())

    if err != nil {
        return Services{}, fmt.Errorf("error runnning search query: %s", err)
    }

    aggregation := res.Aggregations["services"]

    servicesAgg, ok := aggregation.(*types.StringTermsAggregate)
    if !ok {
        return nil, errors.New("incorrect aggregation type")
    }
    
    buckets, ok := servicesAgg.Bucket([]types.StringTermsBucket)
    if !ok {
        return nil, errors.New("incorrect aggregation buckets type")
    }

    for _, bucket := range buckets {
        key, ok := item.Key.(string)
        if !ok {
            continue
        }
      // Do something with key
    }

    return result, err
}
```